# Memory issue with SAX Parser in Android

Tags: android, saxparser

I'm actually using SAX Parser the first time. From tutorials and questions here I could figure most things out, nearly everything is working fine now. But I have still one problems. When parsing logcat shows me many Garbage-Collector Logs. And sometimes there occur also grow heap messages. And if this happens, there are always wrong items created.
Perhaps someone here has some optimization suggestions.

This is the code of the handler's characters method, the parser always parses the complete file, afterwards all found items are stored in a sqlite table:

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    //decide wich tag is active, process string

    String parse = new String(ch, start, length);

    if(in_starttag)
    {
        currentItem = new Item();
        in_starttag = false;
    }
    else if(in_mainclasstag)
    {
        if(cats.indexOf(parse) == -1)
        {
            cats.add(parse);

            currentMain = new EgrohItem((categories.size()+1), parse, 1, -1);
            categories.add(currentMain);
        }
        else
        {
            currentMain = categories.get(cats.indexOf(parse));
        }
    }
    else if(in_midclasstag)
    {
        if(cats.indexOf(parse) == -1)
        {
            cats.add(parse);
            currentMid = new EgrohItem((categories.size()+1), parse, 0, currentMain.getId());
            categories.add(currentMid);
        }
        else
        {
            currentMid = categories.get(cats.indexOf(parse));
        }
    }
    else if(in_subclasstag)
    {
        if(cats.indexOf(parse) == -1)
        {
            cats.add(parse);
            currentSub = new EgrohItem((categories.size()+1), parse, 0, currentMid.getId());
            categories.add(currentSub);
        }
        else
        {
            currentSub = categories.get(cats.indexOf(parse));
        }
        currentItem.setAbove_cat(currentMain.getId());
    }
    else if(in_idtag)
    {
        currentItem.setArt_nr(parse);
    }
    else if(in_destag1)
    {
        if(currentItem.getName() != null)
        {
            currentItem.setName(currentItem.getName() + parse);
        }
        else currentItem.setName(parse);
    }
    else if(in_destag2)
    {
        if(currentItem.getName() != null)
        {
            currentItem.setName(currentItem.getName() + parse);
        }
        else currentItem.setName(parse);
    }
    else if(in_destag3)
    {
        if(currentItem.getName() != null)
        {
            currentItem.setName(currentItem.getName() + parse);
        }
        else currentItem.setName(parse);
    }
    else if(in_destag4)
    {
        if(currentItem.getName() != null)
        {
            currentItem.setName(currentItem.getName() + parse);
        }
        else currentItem.setName(parse);
    }
    else if(in_descriptag)
    {
        if(currentItem.getDescription() != null)
        {
            String des = currentItem.getDescription()+" "+parse;
            currentItem.setDescription(des);
        }
        else currentItem.setDescription(parse);
    }
    else if(in_eantag)
    {
        currentItem.setEan(parse);
    }
    else if(in_suppnrtag)
    {
        currentItem.setSupp_nr(parse);
    }
    else if(in_supptag)
    {
        currentItem.setSupplier(parse);
    }
    else if(in_acctag1)
    {
        currentAcc_Nr = parse;
        currentItem.setAccessories_number(currentAcc_Nr);
    }
    else if(in_acctag2)
    {
        if(parse.length()>0 && !parse.equals(" "))
        {
            currentAcc_Nr += parse;
        }
        currentItem.setAccessories_number(currentAcc_Nr);
    }
    else if(in_acctag3)
    {
        if(parse.length()>0 && !parse.equals(" "))
        {
            currentAcc_Nr += parse;
        }
        currentItem.setAccessories_number(currentAcc_Nr);
    }
    else if(in_acctag4)
    {
        if(parse.length()>0 && !parse.equals(" "))
        {
            currentAcc_Nr += parse;
        }
        currentItem.setAccessories_number(currentAcc_Nr);
    }
    else if(in_amount1tag)
    {
        Integer amo1 = new Integer(parse);
        currentItem.setAmo1(amo1);
    }
    else if(in_amount2tag)
    {
        Integer amo2 = new Integer(parse);
        if(amo2 > 0) currentItem.setAmo2(amo2);
    }
    else if(in_amount3tag)
    {
        Integer amo3 = new Integer(parse);
        if(amo3 > 0) currentItem.setAmo3(amo3);
    }
    else if(in_price1tag)
    {
        currentItem.setPrice1(parse);
    }
    else if(in_price2tag)
    {
        if(!parse.equals("0")) currentItem.setPrice2(parse);
    }
    else if(in_price3tag)
    {
        if(!parse.equals("0")) currentItem.setPrice3(parse);
    }
    else if(in_mctag)
    {
        categories.get(currentMain.getId()-1).setName(parse);
    }
    else if(in_mictag)
    {
        categories.get(currentMid.getId()-1).setName(parse);
    }
}
```

and the part where the parsing is started:
    try
        {
            URL src = new URL(src_url);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

```
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        MedExampleHandler meh = new MedExampleHandler(prefcon);
        xr.setContentHandler(meh);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(src.openStream(), 200);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(bis);
        xr.parse(is);

        categories = meh.getCategories();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(EgrohCatalogue.TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

Thank you very much for every suggestion!

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? All you've posted is a bunch of `if else if else if else` statements. Have you thought about using a SAX parser library? Android has one built in...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/package-summary.html

Comment: Sorry, I thought this would be the part that causes performance issues. I have an parser class that creates handler and so, I've added the code above. And the handler creates an arraylist of items. In start/end element methods I'm just setting the bool variables, adding the created items to the list and releasing the afterwards. No, never thought of this library, just did it the way like all the tutorials, but I will have a look, how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must not write your all codes by overiding right methods like startDocument, startElements, endElements, endDocuments along with characters method.

Please see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) example.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see, what you mean. From my point of view the example looks similar to what I have... Like mentioned above, I have a StartDocument method where the lists are created, a startElement method, where the bools are set to true and a endElement method, where the bools are set to false.

Comment: you have only over ride "characters" method. At least you need to override startDocument and startElements methods. Please refer the link carefully.

Comment: Sorry, I was perhaps a little bit imprecise this time, above only the character method is shown, I thought it would get too long if I paste the complete method. And I also thought it's much more probable to find the mistake in the characters method than in the others.